# Base operand of '->' has non-pointer type

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement the A* algorithm in C++. Everything seems to work, except drawing the path the algorithm found.

```
    for(int i = 0; i<succesor.size(); i++){
        if(tab[succesor[i].x][succesor[i].y] == 'E'){
            node s = succesor[i];
            while(s.parent != NULL){
                tab[s.x][s.y] = '*';
                s = s->parent;
            }
        } 
    }
```

And here is my node struct:

```
struct node{
    node *parent;
    int x, y;
    double f, g, h;
};
```

Comment: I think you mean `s = *s.parent;`

Comment: Oh god, you're right. I was sitting on this for the last hour and didn't see that. Thanks a lot

Comment: You are copying nodes. This doesn't mesh well with pointers. Where's "the" parent of the node if there are several copies of it floating around? `s->parent` can only point to one copy.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid copying the whole `node` structure try this:

```
for(int i = 0; i<succesor.size(); i++){
    if(tab[succesor[i].x][succesor[i].y] == 'E'){
        node* s = &succesor[i];
        while(s->parent != NULL){
            tab[s->x][s->y] = '*';
            s = s->parent;
        }
    } 
}
```